# Paging Horizontally with vertical scroll on each page!

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

In my app I use a page control and a UIScrollView to page horizontally, I'd like to be able to enable vertical scrolling on each page. Now I know you can nest UIScrollViews in order to achieve this, there is however one problem in my project. Each of the pages  uses a view controller consisting of a view, with a background image (different image for each page). This background image should not move while scrolling up and down.

Now what I want is the ability to have buttons, regular rect buttons, which I create in Interface Builder (since I want to be able to design and update the positions easily) and which then can be scrolled vertically.

So it should be like this:

You see a screen with a page-control on the bottom, above it an image with buttons over it. When you scroll sideways, you go to another page, again with an image (another one) and with different buttons. Now whenever you scroll vertically on a page, the buttons should be scrollable (so I can have a LOT of buttons on 1 page), but the image should maintain it's position.

So I figured, I just add another scroll view on top of the view with the background image. This works fine since I now have my buttons hovering over the background image and I have a separate nib file for each page including the buttons.  But when I do it like this, the scrollview with the buttons becomes un-scrollable vertically. I don't know why this is happening, so could anyone suggest me how to achieve the wanted result?

I'd be really really grateful!

Thanks,

Fabian

Comment: Are you setting the contentSize of the scroll views with the buttons? It sounds like your scroll view is being sized to fit within your outer paginated scroll view, but the contentSize is not being set.